# Why apktool is not decoding versionCode and versionName?

Tags: android, apktool

I'm using apktool using the following command

```
apktool decode "[APK PATH]"
```

For some reason the decoded androidmanifest.xml doesn't contain attributes `versionCode` and `versionName`. I know they are there on the original file since, if I open the encoded file, I can see the attribute in the middle of the encrypted text.

I need to verify if the versionCode is automatically updated by gradle after implementing some code to do this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it is saved to another file. as I remember, some extension with .yml. when you again encode the package, apktool command uses this file for versionCode

Comment: is this referring to the apktool.yml file?  If so, and it says "2.0.0" but you want to use the apktool.jar version 2.0.0 RC4, would you need to change that yml file for a wraping GUI like MDXToolkit to see a jar that's been updated?